Adding ScrollView to FloatLayout
relativley new to Kivy. trying to add a ScrollView to my FloatLayout. It actually worked before on another application.But now when I run this application the ScrollView doesn't fill the Parent. Opens a small window at the botoom left were its scrolling but barely visible. Does the same if I replace the FloatLayout with a BoxLayout only fills the parent if I remove the size_hint and use size: root.width, root.height but that messes up the scrolling by creating permanentyly fixed widgets and shadows that scroll up and down.
python code:
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window 

Builder.load_file('my.kv')

class AddJob(Widget):
    pass

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AddJob() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()```


(.kv code)

```<AddJob>:
    ScrollView:
        size_hint: (1, 1)
        do_scroll_y: True
        do_scroll_x: False
        size_hint_x: None
        size_hint_y: None
        
        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height * 2
            size_hint_y: None
            
            TextInput:
                text: 'Job Number'
                size: (400, 50)
                size_hint_y: None
                font_size: 40
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.5}
            
            TextInput:
                text: 'Test'
                size: (400, 50)
                font_size: 40
                size_hint_y: None
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.6}```






Trying to Add a ScrollView to a FloatLayout.


Two issues with your code. First, you are using the Widget class as a container, but the Widget is not intended to be used as a container, and does not support things like size_hint. Instead of defining AddJob as extending Widget, try using a Layout class (which is intended to be used as a container). For example:
class AddJob(FloatLayout):
    pass

Second, in your ScrollView you use:
    size_hint_x: None
    size_hint_y: None

This code results in the size of the ScrollView remaining at the default size of (100, 100). If you delete these lines, the ScrollView will fill its parent. Also, the line:
    size_hint: (1, 1)

has no effect, since the default setting for size_hint is (1, 1). Also, the default setting for do_scroll_y is True, so that is another line that is unnecessary. So you ScrollView could be defined as simply:
ScrollView:
    do_scroll_x: False


Thank you. What worked was removing this line of code '''Builder.load_file('my.kv')''' At runtime there was a message that I hadn't seen stating that the (.kv) file is being called more than once and might create layout issues. Removing the line stopped the shadowing effect when scrolling.
